# reusing a third-party by WebRTC itself and other business

Tags: ios, dynamic, webrtc, code-reuse, opus

This is the scene as follows:

1. I have a opus framework named opus.framework,which is a dynamic library on the iOS-platform and will be used by some other business 
   ,assuming this business is "A".
2. there is a third-party  opus codec within WebRTC project,but now I
   wanna replace it to opus.framework mentioned before. so that "A"
   and WebRTC itself can reuse the same opus.framework.
3. WebRTC.framework is compiled as a dynamic framework.
4. And for sure,We can load opus.framework earlier than
   WebRTC.framework

I modified  ./webrtc/modules/audio_coding/BUILD.gn for compiling "webrtc_opus" as follows

```
rtc_static_library("webrtc_opus") {
  sources = [
    "codecs/opus/audio_decoder_opus.cc",
    "codecs/opus/audio_decoder_opus.h",
    "codecs/opus/audio_encoder_opus.cc",
    "codecs/opus/audio_encoder_opus.h",
    "codecs/opus/opus_inst.h",
    "codecs/opus/opus_interface.c",
    "codecs/opus/opus_interface.h",
  ]

  deps = [
    ":audio_decoder_interface",
    ":audio_encoder_interface",
    ":audio_network_adaptor",
    "../../base:rtc_base_approved",
  ]

  if (rtc_build_opus) {
   //opus.framework is located at /src/extern/opus/ in the WebRTC source project
   include_dirs=["//extern/opus","//extern/opus/opus.framework/Headers"]
   rpath_link="//extern/opus/"
   ldflags = ["-Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN/${rpath_link}",
              "-Wl,-rpath-link=${rpath_link}",
              "-force_load"]

   libs = ["opus.framework"]
  } 
}
```

And I got errors as follows:

```
    ld: framework not found opus
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../build/toolchain/mac/linker_driver.py", line 229, in <module>
    Main(sys.argv)
  File "../../build/toolchain/mac/linker_driver.py", line 79, in Main
    subprocess.check_call(compiler_driver_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++', '-shared', '-all_load', '-Xlinker', '-install_name', '-Xlinker', '@rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC', '-Xlinker', '-objc_abi_version', '-Xlinker', '2', '-arch', 'arm64', '-Wl,-dead_strip', '-isysroot', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.1.sdk', '-stdlib=libc++', '-miphoneos-version-min=8.0', '-Wl,-ObjC', '-L../../extern/opus', '-o', 'obj/webrtc/sdk/arm64/WebRTC', '-Wl,-filelist,obj/webrtc/sdk/arm64/WebRTC.rsp', '-framework', 'AVFoundation', '-framework', 'AudioToolbox', '-framework', 'CoreGraphics', '-framework', 'CoreMedia', '-framework', 'GLKit', '-framework', 'VideoToolbox', '-framework', 'CoreFoundation', '-framework', 'CoreText', '-framework', 'Foundation', '-framework', 'CFNetwork', '-framework', 'Security', '-framework', 'SystemConfiguration', '-framework', 'UIKit', '-framework', 'CoreVideo', '-framework', 'OpenGLES', '-framework', 'QuartzCore', '-framework', 'opus']'
```

It will be really appreciated if anyone can pull me out.Is there a solution for the reuse of opus.framework by "A" and WebRTC?